# Java: How to make a multicast IP InetAddress exclusive?

Tags: java, networking, broadcast, multicast

I'm trying to make a multicast IP exclusive, i.e. it can be "locked" and when it is "locked", no more MulticastSocket can join it.

Is it possible? How do I do it? Here's some code to explain my case:

```
String multicastIP = "224.0.0.1"; //multicast IP to "lock" later
InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(multicastIP); //create group

MulticastSocket multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket(8800); //Create a MulticastSocket using port 8800
multicastSocket.joinGroup(group); //join the group

//This is the part where I want to "lock" the group/IP
```

Additional information:

I'm developing a network game where the single server to multiple clients broadcasting scheme is done via this method.

There was a time we created two servers (that happen to have the same multicast IP) and incidentally, the clients listen to both servers, receiving messages from both servers.

What we want to happen is to make the clients listen only to their respective servers.

Thanks! :D

Comment: you can limit access to multicast thru router configuration, but not in java, and that router lmiitation is just whether it forwards packets. You would have to use packet data fields to limit who responds to what.

Comment: Oh, thanks. But we need it done via the program. So you're saying it cannot be done in Java?

Comment: Just ignore any packets that aren't from your server. Drop them as soon as you receive them. UDP applications always have to deal with "stray" packets from previous sessions or random garbage. Just write code to drop them.

Comment: You need to join a group to listen to packets. If you allowed only one joiner, no-one can hear you (scream ;).

Answer (score 2):

Multicast won't do this for you.

You will have to examine each incoming packet [when you receive it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive%28java.net.DatagramPacket%29) and match it against the `(source address, source port)` tuple the client is sending from.

Honestly I don't think there is much advantage to using muticast for this. One approach I have seen is to use multicast for service discovery, and then use unicast for the "real" protocol once you have discovered it.

**Edit**: For a LAN application, multicast may be acceptable. I would just be careful not to broadcast too much. (multicasts are essentially broadcasts to most switches; they are filtered out by the NIC rather than the network) That is, ideally make sure the server is the one sending the multicast traffic while the clients unicast updates to the server. (if every client multicasts state updates that all other clients can see, what's the purpose of having the server?)

Comment: Wouldn't using unicast be a slow approach for programming a network game involving many clients and one server?

Comment: @brain56, +1 Only when you get close to the maximum bandwidth of your network. Most server would expect to have a 1 Gb network connection. TCP is much easier to program for reliably and I suggest you implement this first and change it when you have a need.

Comment: @brain56, I don't know. Depends on the scale and the use case for your game. Do you expect it to play only on a local area network, or is this for internet gaming? What happens if someone starts up a 2nd server? (can that even happen, or is there only ever one server?)

Comment: @Mike, the game will only be played on LAN, but clients can range in numbers from three to ten to twenty. It is also going to happen that two servers in the same network can exist at the same time.

Comment: @brain56, how does the client select which game it wants? (Why not use multiple multicast addresses instead, to avoid this problem?) Also, do the clients trust updates from all the other clients? Why even have a server if you're using multicast? Would it be better to unicast updates about each client to the server, then have the server multicast the game state back out to the network?

Comment: @Mike, the clients select a server to connect to by specifying an IP address.

I find your idea of the clients communicating to the server via unicast and the server broadcasting to the clients via multicast. We'll give it a try. Thanks.